# How to connect flash[:notice] in ruby module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have module mangopay_helper.rb

```
module MangoPayHelper

  def transfer_to_contractor(contract, client, contractor) 
    amount = contract.amount * 0,1.to_i
  begin
    MangoPay::Transfer.create({
      Tag: "#{contract.id} + #{contract.title}",
      AuthorId: client.mangopay_id,
      DebitedFunds: {Currency: "EUR", Amount: contract.amount},
      Fees:  { Currency: 'EUR', Amount: amount},
      DebitedWalletId: client.wallet_id,
      CreditedWalletId: contractor.wallet_id
    })
  rescue MangoPay::ResponseError => e 
     flash[:notice] = " Code: #{ e['Code'] } Message: #{ e['Message'] }"
  end  
  end
end
```

In action of controller I call `MangoPayHelper.transfer_to_contractor` .

```
Error: undefined local variable or method `flash' for MangoPayHelper:Module
```

How can I connect flash in ruby module?

Comment: pass flash as argument of the method `transfer_to_contractor`

Comment: But why do you want to modify `flash` from helper? That is not good approach, controller is the right place to play with `flash`.

Comment: i removed flash from module, but same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (and should) let the controller handle the manipulation of the `flash` hash.

```
module MangoPayHelper
  def self.transfer_to_contractor!(contract, client, contractor) 
    amount = contract.amount * 0,1.to_i

    MangoPay::Transfer.create({
      Tag: "#{contract.id} + #{contract.title}",
      AuthorId: client.mangopay_id,
      DebitedFunds: {Currency: "EUR", Amount: contract.amount},
      Fees:  { Currency: 'EUR', Amount: amount},
      DebitedWalletId: client.wallet_id,
      CreditedWalletId: contractor.wallet_id
    })
  end
end
```

---

```
class TransfersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # [...]
    begin
      MangoPayHelper.transfer_to_contractor!(contract, client, contractor)
    rescue MangoPay::ResponseError => e 
      flash[:notice] = " Code: #{ e['Code'] } Message: #{ e['Message'] }"
    end
    # [...]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, calling `MangoPayHelper.transfer_to_contractor` with your code shouldn't even work because you have `def transfer_to_contractor` - you'd need `def self.transfer_to_contractor` to make it callable like that.

`flash` is a controller method. To make it callable from the module, you'd `include` the module in your controller and then call the method like `transfer_to_contractor` instead of `MangoPayHelper.transfer_to_contractor`. When you include a module, the module then gains access to the includer's methods such as `flash`.

for example,

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  include MongoPayHelper
  def my_route
    transfer_to_controller(some args)
    etc
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you, uninitialized constant ContractsController::MangoPayHelpererror. module store in folder `lib`

Comment: OK well now that's an error about where your module is defined. Try doing it in a file in the config/initializers folder